# bluetooth dongle recognised but no function at startup, but does function after unplug-plug (edited)

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth

kernel 6.5.6 , Ubuntu 22.04. , ASUS MB.
Barrot bluetooth dongle (supposedly fully compatible with CSR)

After desktop startup, the dongle shows in lsusb.  But will not function.
When I unplug the dongle, then plug in again, the dongle will function.

Why?  Any possibility to have the dongle functioning upon startup, with no unplug-plug procedure?  Do I need a kernel patch?

Thank you.

1/ results of commands upon startup...

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 33fa:0001  USB2.0-BT

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 04:7F:0E:54:D1:87  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN
RX bytes:165 acl:0 sco:0 events:9 errors:0
TX bytes:273 acl:0 sco:0 commands:10 errors:0
Features: 0xbf 0xee 0xcd 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV3
Link policy:
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT

2/ result of commands after unplug-plug procedure...

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 04:7F:0E:54:D1:87  ACL MTU: 1021:9  SCO MTU: 255:4
UP RUNNING PSCAN
RX bytes:838 acl:0 sco:0 events:68 errors:0
TX bytes:3243 acl:0 sco:0 commands:67 errors:0
Features: 0xbf 0xee 0xcd 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV3
Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT
Name: me
Class: 0x6c0104
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x89
LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0x89
Manufacturer: Barrot Technology Limited (2279)

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.  Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show system logs that cover the event. Read `man journalctl`. Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in `[]` of the issuer and a colon (`:`). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read `man logger`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, and the resultant tutorial.  The log shows the dongle is detected at boot, which is confirmed by the lsusb command. But I know not what to search in the log to determine why the dongle does not function after boot, nor would I know the meaning of any lines if I could find an entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to the fact that you have "non standard" kernel.
*See https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle at "Kernel release schedule" (click on 22.04)*

A possible "fix"... what happens if you do:

```
$ bluetoothctl power off
Changing power off succeeded

$ bluetoothctl power on
[CHG] Controller xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Class: 0x000yyyyy
Changing power on succeeded

$
```

Does BT turn up after the software power cycling, above?

Now this does not tell why it ends up in this state though.

---

One more thing to try:

```
$ rfkill block bluetooth

$ sleep 2

$ rfkill unblock bluetooth

$
```

Comment: @ Hannu... Many thanks for your comment!  1/ The power-on works.  I added the command to the startup options. BT now powered-on at boot.  2/ I feel foolish for overlooking such a basic condition. Lesson: never assume anything.  But, thanks.  3/ I had not thought of the kernel version. I shall investigate this.  - best wishes to you.

Comment: If you consider this ta have helped you, please upvote or mark it as "the answer"- see https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: After a system upgrade, the method above no longer worked.  I bought a new dongle: Realtek chipset.  Works plug-n-play.