# bluetooth dongle not recognised anymore, but does function after unplug-plug

Tags: bluetooth, reset, dongle

I have a generic bluetooth dongle. It worked fine with my rapoo mouse but after changing the mouse to a generic one (from aliexpress) the OS doesn't recognize it anymore on startup.
It recognizes it after unplug-plug of the dongle and then it works.
How will i get it to do it automatically?

I'm running Ubuntu Lts 22.04.3

---

I have tried the steps described here:
[bluetooth dongle recognised but no function at startup, but does function after unplug-plug (edited)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493625/bluetooth-dongle-recognised-but-no-function-at-startup-but-does-function-after)

1. I haven't seen anything in the journalctl log related to bluetooth. what's the process name i should be looking at for errors?
2. *lsusb* shows

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

3. *hciconfig -a* shows

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 04:7F:0E:41:16:91  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN
RX bytes:179 acl:0 sco:0 events:10 errors:0
TX bytes:276 acl:0 sco:0 commands:11 errors:0
Features: 0xbf 0xee 0xcd 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV3
Link policy:
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT

4. *bluetoothctl power on* shows

No default controller available

---

after unplug-plug it works

2. *lsusb* shows same
3. *hciconfig -a* shows

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 04:7F:0E:41:16:91  ACL MTU: 1021:9  SCO MTU: 255:4
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
RX bytes:290849 acl:16052 sco:0 events:158 errors:0
TX bytes:5783 acl:42 sco:0 commands:103 errors:0
Features: 0xbf 0xee 0xcd 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV3
Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT
Name: 'me'
Class: 0x7c0104
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x89
LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0x89
Manufacturer: Barrot Technology Limited (2279)

4. *bluetootctl power on* (or off) is working

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: You could always write a systemd oneshot service to power usb bus #1 off and on after a delay